# Passing "typedef char IPString[17]" as argument to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference, typedef

I have run into issues (runs on Intel, odd run results on ARM) when using this typedef:

```
typedef char IPString[17];
...
IPString ipStr;
extractIPfromURL("https://192.168.0.1:80", ipStr);
```

NOTE: I CANNOT use std::string, because code needs to compile on GCC and IAR.  While IAR does support std::string the rule is not to use it.

If extractIPfromURL signature is:

```
void extractIPfromURL(const char* url, IPString *ipStr);
```

and implementation uses:

```
const char* ep;
...
strncpy(ipStr[0], &ep[start], end-start+1);
*ipStr[end+1] = '\0';
```

caller for pointer:

```
IPString ipStr;
extractIPfromURL("https://192.168.0.1:80", &ipStr);
```

everything works.

But if I was to use signature:

```
void extractIPfromURL(const char* url, IPString &ipStr);
```

and implementation:

```
const char* ep;
...
strncpy(&ipStr[0], &ep[start], end-start+1);
ipStr[end+1] = '\0';
```

caller for reference:

```
IPString ipStr;
extractIPfromURL("https://192.168.0.1:80", ipStr);
```

The code on ARM appears to behave as I rewrote some of the stack and my loop that is supposed to iterate over 2 items iterates over 2 items forever like: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, etc.

I tried an explicit reference declaration:

```
typedef char (&IPStringRef)[17];
```

but got the same loop on ARM (Raspberry PI).

I am sure I am not using typedef correctly in here, but I don't understand what exactly is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use std::string

Comment: "Everything works"? This does not seem to make sense, since in that case `*ipStr[end+1] = '\0';` inside `extractIPfromURL` is wrong. You would need `(*ipStr)[end+1] = '\0';` in that case. The parentheses are absolutely required. Otherwise, the code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Does it really make sense to pass arrays by reference? Why not use `void extractIPfromURL(const char* url, IPString ipStr);` directly? (The array decays to a pointer to its first element anyway.)

Comment: Perhaps there's some undefined behaviour in the `...` part.

Comment: @Cameron: It actually makes perfect sense if you want to enforce a specific array type (the size specifically). In fact, the is the *proper* way to do it. Passing `IPString ipStr` as parameter should be reserved for situations when array size is variable (and in that case the size should normally be passed as an extra parameter).

Comment: @Sergei G: There's something inaccurate in your description. You first version is actually broken and will typically "overwrite the stack" because of `*ipStr[end+1] = '\0';` error. Meanwhile, your second version (with a reference) looks fine at least at the first sight (assuming you don't overrun the array for some other reason). The "reversed" behavior you observe is unexplainable from the information you provided so far.

Comment: I have many of the same questions.  I hoped someone can explain :)

Comment: I will attempt to write a simple test case in the effort to reproduce the problem cleaner.  It will have to wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear. Part-way down the question you say you say "If [I do this] everything works". So the obvious solution is: do that.

I am assuming that you are asking why the code you posted bits of at the start of the question doesn't work.

Assuming that code is:

```
typedef char IPString[17];
void extractIPfromURL(const char* url, IPString *ipStr);

void some_function(void)
{
    IPString ipStr;
    extractIPfromURL("https://192.168.0.1:80", ipStr);
}
```

You should get a compilation error.  If you don't see an error message then it is time to adjust the flags you pass to the compiler.  The code is a constraint violation because the argument type `char *` does not match the parameter type `char (*)[17]`.

The argument should match the parameter type. You have (at least) three different options for the argument: `IPstring`, `IPstring *`, `IPstring &`. They will all work , so long as you pass the matching argument form, and you use the parameter correctly inside the function (and your code doesn't contain any other bugs of course).

If you are still having trouble then try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment it is anybody's guess what is causing the problem you see on ARM since you only posted bits and pieces.

You could also consider not using the typedef at all.

---

This code is suspicious:

```
strncpy(&ipStr[0], &ep[start], end-start+1);
ipStr[end+1] = '\0';
```

If `start` is not zero then you are placing the `\0` some distance past the end of where you actually finished copying characters. I would recommend avoiding `strncpy` entirely as it is relatively difficult both to use correctly, and to verify correct use of when you are reviewing code later.